# Flask block 'content' defined twice

Tags: python, html, flask, web

When I run the page I get this error message:

> `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'endblock'.`

I tried to find the source of the problem but found nothing.

***Code:***

```
{% extends "/base.html" %}
{% block title %}Main site{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Test<h1>
{% endblock %}
```

***Error code:***

For the entire error message, the image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the linked traceback image, your problem is in the file `/base.html`, on line 7. Seems like `/base.html` contains 2 `content` blocks (the second one defined on line 7 in that file).